# Select a unique value throughout all the rows having a particular value for column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, having

I have a requirement which needs to fetch all the distinct records for key which has a particular value for all rows, and not if it has some other value in other rows.

Table structure:

```
  Select TOP (1000)
   [Old_Branch_Code]
  ,[Computer_Name]
  ,[Migrated]
  ,[Migration_Date]
  FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[ABS_Computer_Details]
```

So, if the table ABS_Computer_Details contains the records like

```
  1, 'X', 'SUCCESS','12/12/12'
  1, 'Y', 'SUCCESS','12/12/12'
  1, 'Z', 'SUCCESS','12/12/12'
  1, 'W', 'Failed','12/12/12'
  2, 'Y', 'SUCCESS','12/12/12'
  2, 'Z', 'SUCCESS','12/12/12'
  3, 'Z', 'Failed','12/12/12'
  4, 'Z', 'SUCCESS','12/12/12'
```

So, it should ***only*** select branch_code = 2 and branch_code = 4; because one of the column for branch_code = 1 and branch_code = 3 has status = 'Failed'.

My attempt:

```
select Old_Branch_Code from dbo.ABS_Computer_Details
group by Old_Branch_Code,Migrated having Migrated='SUCCESS'
```

But, my query is returning values for branch_code = 1, branch_code = 2 and branch_code = 4. As per my requirement, I should've got branch_code = 2 and branch_code = 4 only.

**Off-topic:** I know this is very trivial, but I'm poor with DB queries as I'm not a DBA guy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach here is to use conditional aggregation in the `HAVING` clause which checks for the presence of any migration other than `SUCCESS`.  If we can't find anything other than `SUCCESS` then we retain that branch code.

```
SELECT Old_Branch_Code
FROM dbo.ABS_Computer_Details
GROUP BY Old_Branch_Code
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN migrated != 'SUCCESS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: Perfect answer, exactly what I wanted. +1, and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter records `NOT EXISTS`. You can get all the columns as follows.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.ABS_Computer_Details A
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (   
        SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ABS_Computer_Details B
        WHERE
            B.Old_Branch_Code = A.Old_Branch_Code AND
            B.Migrated = 'Failed'
    )
```

Comment: Works, but, Tim's answer gave me what exactly I wanted. +1.

Answer (score -2):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT Old_Branch_Code,
       Computer_Name,
       Migration_Date
FROM ABS_Computer_Details
WHERE Old_Branch_Code NOT IN ( SELECT Old_Branch_Code AS failedBranchCode
                               FROM ABS_Computer_Details
                               WHERE Migrated = 'FAILED'
                               GROUP BY Old_Branch_Code
                            )
ORDER BY Old_Branch_Code,
         Computer_Name,
         Migration_Date;
```

This statement starts by using a subquery to find a list of all `Old_Branch_Code` values that *do* have a `Migrated` value of `FAILED` associated with them.

The main statement then selects every record where `Old_Branch_Code` does *not* belong to this list.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

*Appendix*

I have tested my code against a database created using the following script...

```
CREATE TABLE ABS_Computer_Details
(
    Old_Branch_Code   INT,
    Computer_Name     VARCHAR( 20 ),
    Migrated          VARCHAR( 20 ),
    Migration_Date    DATE
);
INSERT INTO ABS_Computer_Details ( Old_Branch_Code,
                                   Computer_Name,
                                   Migrated,
                                   Migration_Date )
VALUES ( 1, 'X', 'SUCCESS', '2012/12/13' ),
       ( 1, 'Y', 'SUCCESS', '2012/12/13' ),
       ( 1, 'Z', 'SUCCESS', '2012/12/13' ),
       ( 1, 'W', 'Failed',  '2012/12/13' ),
       ( 2, 'Y', 'SUCCESS', '2012/12/13' ),
       ( 2, 'Z', 'SUCCESS', '2012/12/13' ),
       ( 3, 'Z', 'Failed',  '2012/12/13' ),
       ( 4, 'Z', 'SUCCESS', '2012/12/13' );
```

Comment: After changing `WHER` to `WHERE` it worked just fine.